# LDAP insert new user

Tags: php, server, ldap

I have windows server 2012 and i want to insert new user using ldap and php 
the connection to ldap server is ok but I can not insert new user 
and I have more than one error every time I change the dn code 
the last error I have is 
**Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Naming violation in C:\AppServ\www\auth\insert.php on line 36**
the code of my  php file is

```html
<?php
$ip          = "10.10.10.35:389";
$ldap_url    = "ldap://$ip";
$ldaps_url   = "ldaps://$ip";
$ldap_domain = 'peace.world';
$ldap_dn     = "dc=peace,dc=world";


$ldap_conn = ldap_connect($ldap_url) 
  or die("Could not connect to LDAP server ($ldap_url)");
echo $ldap_con;
if ($ldap_conn)
    echo " connected";

$username = "captiveportal";
$password = "123";

$result = ldap_bind($ldap_conn, "$username@$ldap_domain", $password) 
  or die("<br>Error: Couldn't bind to server using supplied credentials!");

if ($result) {
    
    ldap_set_option($ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    $dn = "cn=Users,DC=peace,DC=world";
    
    echo $dn;
    
    $info["cn"]          = "muh Jones";
    $info["sn"]          = "muh";
    $info["objectclass"] = "person";
    
    
    try {

## Heading ##    

$r = ldap_add($ldap_conn, $dn, $info);//36 line the error is here
--------------------------------------


    }
    
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
    
} else
    echo "cannot connect to ldap";
```

the image of my active directorty users and computers is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yphll.png)

Comment: Can you mark line 36 and can you remove the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: this is 36 line                                                                                                 
 $r = ldap_add($ldap_conn, $dn, $info);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do indeed have a naming violation. You are trying to add a new entry with DN "cn=Users,dc=Peace,=dc=world" but that DN is already taken as it's the DN of the entry that holds all users. You most likely want to add a DN "cn=muh Jones,cn=Users,dc=Peace,dc=world"

Besides that there are probably some attributes missing like f.e. samaccountname but thats most likely not what causes your error.

Additionally I'd recommend to set the Protocol version right after the ldap_connect!